# Erro ao abrir projeto Android React-Native no AndroidStudio através do MacOS

Tags: android-studio, react-native, mac

Estou tentando abrir um projeto `Android React-Native` existente através do `AndroidStudio`, porém as seguintes exceptions são exibidas para mim:

```
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Unable to save ...local.properties (Permission denied)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: ...local.properties (Permission denied)
```

Meu sistema operacional é o MacOs e projeto Android foi criado pelo comando:

`react-native init exercicios`

Como posso resolver ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que o comando `react-native init exercícios` não estava criando o projeto corretamente.

Precisei alterar as permissões de leitura e escrita na pasta do projeto para poder funcionar corretamente.

Segui as dicas deste link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691435/android-studio-externalsystemexception

Answer (score 0):

Como o erro indica (`permission denied`), o seu usuário não tem permissões pra alterar o arquivo `local.properties`. Esse arquivo serve para indicar o diretório do SDK no computador e é armazenado na pasta do projeto. Ele tem apenas uma linha não comentada (semelhante a `sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk`).

Para resolver o problema, verifique primeiro se o usuário que você está logado tem permissões de escrita na pasta do projeto; e se necessário, inicie o Android Studio como Administrador.